# I have an issue with booting into ubuntu because I messed up my drive /dev/sda4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

So I messed up something when I changed C drive size on windows (I have dual boot) and now Ubuntu does not want to boot and I see this

```
/dev/sda4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda4 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

After I try to fix it with `fsck /dev/sda4` and it gives me the following

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 14486016 blocks
The physical size of the device is 12313088 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort<y>? no
```

I press no and then press yes all the way until the end where it says

```
/dev/sda4: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda4: 535856/3614880 files (1.0% non-contiguous), 8131805/14486016 blocks
```

Even after this my Ubuntu does no boot normally but tells me UNEXPETCED INCONSISTENCY.

I have tried to use fsck from Live Ubuntu USB but same result

Since I messed up with a partition, can this be solved with Gparted or something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually with dual boot you have C drive and then Ubuntu partition.  If this was your case, you did move Ubuntu to the right to give space to expand C drive first?  Do you have important data on Ubuntu partition?  If no important to you data, the easiest would be to re-install Ubuntu on newer partition.  Windows does not see Ubuntu/Linux as being important use of space on drive.

Comment: Thanks for help. I actually made C drive smaller in Windows disk manager to free up to space for Ubuntu partition. This was "succesful" but now it says that filesystem size is bigger than the actual physical size of the device. There is no way to resize because the partition is corrupted and unfixable i think.

Comment: Did you use Windows or gparted on a Live USB stick to expand Ubuntu?  Windows probably made a mess of things if done from Windows.  Being lazy and not an expert myself, Would try to copy data from Ubuntu with a USB, and then re install(easy and fast).  The experts on here might be able to help redo your partition tables to fix.

Comment: Always use `Windows Disk Management` to handle NTFS partitions, and `gparted` to handle linux partitions. Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB, start `gparted`, and use the **Check** option on the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: So I did not expand ubuntu partition in any way, I just made Windows partition smaller (shouldn't affect ububtu partition?) in windows disk manager in order to later add this free space for ubuntu. I booted into ubuntu live usb and tried fdisk to Check the partition and even resize it. Whats ironic is that I tried to make ubuntu bigger in order to use Timeshift to backup my system lol.